# svg to pdf client side or server side c#, js?

Tags: javascript, c#, pdf, svg, gojs

What is the best way to convert svgToPdf 
Have tried with all sorts of js libraries available like jsPdf, svgToPdf etc.. 
which has only few default shapes like triangle, rectangle, circle etc.. 
If the shapes like in "GoJs" such as, diamond, cylinder etc are not getting converted.
How to get it converted..!
How to handle it, either from the serverside - to - client, or from client-to-server-back_to_client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look to [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/): it can render SVG to PDF (or png/jpg image). Phantomjs is a native program that is actually a headless browser based on WebKit engine.
Usage is rather straightforward (see also [official documentation](http://phantomjs.org/screen-capture.html) on this):

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open('file://c:\path_to_svg\some.svg', function() {
  page.render('svg_export.pdf');
  phantom.exit();
});
```

phantomjs can be executed with System.Diagnostics.Process (or you may use existing wrapper that provides API for executing phantomjs from C# code).

Comment: It looks like command-line tool to execute, so the pdf will be generated from command-line?

Comment: @peaceUser yes your .net program executes phantomjs and it generates PDF file.

Comment: I am not able to embed phantomjs.exe in my asp.net core app, if I give my localSystem path where I have extracted, it gives System.Io Filenot found

Comment: @peaceUser I'm not sure what "embed phantomjs.exe" means in your case. If you target only windows platform, you can just include phantomjs.exe into your distribution package.

Comment: I have added it from Nuget, looks like not able to get the path of it?

Comment: Auto splits the pages, two different pdf files are rendered, how to control this?